# Enable cors on api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services

Im tryng to access my api gateway from a react app, but im getting cors error. I already tried adding the header on the nodejs code

like this

```
module.exports.fetchPokemon = async (event) => {
    try{
        let response = await getPokemon(event.pathParameters.name);
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
              }, body:response};
    }catch(error){
        return error;
    }

};
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to *Management Console* -> *API Gateway*. Click on the resource for which you want CORS to be enabled and click *Actions* -> *Enable CORS* and then *Deploy*.

Another option is to set the `Access-Control` headers via *integration response* -> *header mappings* which you will see when you click on particular method in your resources.

Also, you can't set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` if you have set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true`. What you will need to do in such case is to specify protocol, port and domain instead of `*`, or a list of them.

Comment: Enable cors fails, and integration response is disabled it says Proxy integrations cannot be configured to transform responses.

Comment: @DanielBezerraDeMenezes Then disable proxy integration if you don't really need it.

Comment: no luck,. edited the header mappings with allow origin '*', and still same error. Now the Enable cors action says cors was enabled for the method...but the error persists. fml

Comment: yea i deleted that credentials part. Wierd thinkg is only the POST method gets COrs issue, other methods work fine

Comment: In the end the problem was adding access-allow-origin '*' to the OPTIONS method of the endpoints. For some reason api gateway makes a pre flight request to OPTIONS before the POST. AFter adding the header to the options i had to run the Enable cors also. Thanks for your time tho

Comment: @DanielBezerraDeMenezes It is not the API Gateway that does that, it is a security mechanism of a browser. If browser sees some CORS request, then it first sends preflight OPTIONS request to the server to find out whether the server allows CORS, only then the actual request is sent, whether it is POST, GET or any other. If you are generating request from a REST client instead of browser, then you don't need to set CORS headers at all. Sorry I forgot to mention that.